# How to scrape a paginated website in Python Selenium?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape a [URL](https://www.sec.gov/edgar/search/#/dateRange=custom&category=custom&startdt=2023-08-01&enddt=2023-08-01&forms=10-K%252C10-Q%252C8-K). I have created the script to scrape the required data from the first page. But, I am not able to do the pagination part of it. How can I scrape the data from all the available pages?

```
# Find all rows to iterate through
rows = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="hits"]/table/tbody/tr')

for row in rows:
    # Locate the entity name element within the current row
    entity_name_element = row.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'entity-name')

    # Extract the entity name text
    entity_name = entity_name_element.text

    # Locate the element you want to click (e.g., a link) within the current row
    element_to_click = row.find_element(By.XPATH, './td[1]/a')

    # Click the element
    element_to_click.click()

    # Wait for the <a> element with the ID "open-file" to be clickable
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
    link_element = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "open-file")))

    # Extract the href attribute (the link)
    link = link_element.get_attribute("href")

    # Click the "Close" button by its ID
    close_button = driver.find_element(By.ID, "close-modal")
    close_button.click()
    
    # Print the entity name and link
    print("Entity Name:", entity_name)
    print("Link:", link)
```

Comment: Did you try using their [API](https://www.sec.gov/edgar/sec-api-documentation), instead of inefficiently scraping the website with Selenium?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do it via Selenium (I suggest to do that via their API if possible), you need to implement a loop that:

1. Does `while` loop with break condition
2. If next button is disabled - set break next loop condition to `True`
3. Loop through rows and do your actions
4. After loop you get next page button and check if it is not disabled
5. If it is not disabled - click on it. Wait for rows list to be updated and set new rows to row variable. If it is disabled - do nothing.

I didn't change your locators and comments.
Just added some waits and navigation logic.

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait

url = "https://www.sec.gov/edgar/search/#/dateRange=custom&category=custom&startdt=2023-08-01&enddt=2023-08-01&forms=10-K%252C10-Q%252C8-K"
driver.get(url)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)

rows = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="hits"]/table/tbody/tr')))
break_condition = False
while not break_condition:
    if('disabled' in driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, 'page-item')[-1].get_attribute('className')):
        break_condition = True
    for row in rows: # Locate the entity name element within the current row
        entity_name_element = row.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'entity-name')

        entity_name = entity_name_element.text

        # Locate the element you want to click (e.g., a link) within the current row
        element_to_click = row.find_element(By.XPATH, './td[1]/a')

        # Click the element
        element_to_click.click()

        # Wait for the <a> element with the ID "open-file" to be clickable
        wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
        link_element = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "open-file")))

        # Extract the href attribute (the link)
        link = link_element.get_attribute("href")

        # Click the "Close" button by its ID
        close_button = driver.find_element(By.ID, "close-modal")
        close_button.click()

        # Print the entity name and link
        print("Entity Name:", entity_name)
        print("Link:", link)
    next = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, 'page-item')[-1]
    if ('disabled' not in next.get_attribute('className')):
        next.click()
        wait.until(EC.staleness_of(rows[-1]))
        rows = wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="hits"]/table/tbody/tr')))
```